# Extract highest value from iperf results

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to extract the highest value from iperf log file output ignoring the first entry in line 7.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.10.10.2, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 0.02 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.10.10.1 port 44809 connected with 10.10.10.2 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  2.25 MBytes  18.9 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  2.25 MBytes  18.9 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  2.25 MBytes  18.9 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  2.12 MBytes  17.8 Mbits/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  2.25 MBytes  18.9 Mbits/sec
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-10.1 sec  21.8 MBytes  18.0 Mbits/sec
```

So far I have

```
#!/bin/bash
iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -t 10 -f m -i 1 > /tmp/max.log
sed -i '7d' /tmp/max.log
```

I now need to echo the highest value in the results column 18.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do without the `sed` and just tell awk to ignore everything up through line 7.

```
$ awk 'NR > 7 { max = $(NF-1) > max ? $(NF-1) : max } END { print max }' m.txt
18.9
```